# Obtain the Maximum Value which can be produced by a Function from a Stream Element and the Element itself

Tags: java, java-stream, max

I have a function which computes a value from an object.

And I have code like this:

```
List.stream()
    .max((t1, t2) -> Float.compare(complexFunction(x, t1), complexFunction(x,t2)))
    .get();
```

This successfully gets me the element for which `complexFunction` produces the highest value, but I want to get this value as well.  What's the best way to do this?

I'm thinking that I need to create a map first with all the elements and the values, and then do the max operation after that.  Is there anything better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html), but using a class might be easier.

Define a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395?accessToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImRlZmF1bHQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJhY2Nlc3NfcmVzb3VyY2UiLCJleHAiOjE2NDc4Mjg4MTYsImciOiJlckFkUHk4WE1ZSU1ncEFHIiwiaWF0IjoxNjQ3ODI4NTE2LCJ1c2VySWQiOjYyMzI4fQ.ynfOAzT-LRbKklQwjiPLeDa_CCI6bOqgCISpiPyC3dE) to hold each input `float`, and its resulting computation. Note that a record can be defined locally within a method, or defined separately.

In the old days, some people used `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry`,  [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html), or their interface [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html), or in Java 9+ the convenient [`Map.entry(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)) method, as a [tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) for holding multiple values together. In Java 16+, the need for that vanishes. The new Records feature makes the code more explicit about your invention of a type. Having named fields makes the meaning clear. All the inherited [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html) methods being implicitly created by the compiler makes defining a `record` utterly simple. And the fact that a `record` can be defined locally keeps the code minimal and tidy.

Core example code:

```java
record Comp( Float f , float computed ) { }  // Locally defines an entire class to communicate data transparently and immutably.
Optional < Comp > compOptional =
        list
                .stream()
                .map(
                        f -> new Comp( f , complexFunction( f ) )
                )
                .max(
                        Comparator.comparingDouble( Comp :: computed )
                );
```

We could optimize a bit if we do not care about collecting all the `Comp` records. We could avoid instantiation of all but the winning `Comp` record by simply flipping the order of `.map` and `.max`.

```java
record Comp( Float f , float computed ) { }  // Locally defines an entire class to communicate data transparently and immutably.
Optional < Comp > compOptional =
        list
                .stream()
                .max(
                        Comparator.comparingDouble( App :: complexFunction )
                )
                .map(
                        f -> new Comp( f , complexFunction( f ) )
                );
```

Full example code:

```java
package work.basil.example.modmax;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        List < Float > list = List.of( 7F , 99F , 42F , 1F );

        record Comp( Float f , float computed ) { }  // Locally defines an entire class to communicate data transparently and immutably.
        Optional < Comp > compOptional =
                list
                        .stream()
                        .max(
                                Comparator.comparingDouble( App :: complexFunction )
                        )
                        .map(
                                f -> new Comp( f , complexFunction( f ) )
                        );

        System.out.println( "compOptional = " + compOptional );
    }

    static float complexFunction ( Float f )
    {
        return f * 2;
    }
}
```

When run:

> Optional[Comp[f=99.0, computed=198.0]]

You could play around with `Float` versus `float` to minimize [auto-boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html). But for small amounts of data infrequently processed, I would not bother.

Comment: My eyes hurt...

Comment: Thanks, I did somethings similar to this, although instead of a custom object, I just used AbstractMap.SimpleEntry to create a tuple

Comment: @PeterKronenberg I too have used that hack of `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` or  [`AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry.html). In Java 16+, the need for that vanishes. The new Records feature makes the code more explicit that you are inventing a type. All the inherited `Object` methods being implicitly created by the compiler makes defining a `record` utterly simple. And the fact that a `record` can be defined locally keeps the code minimal and tidy.

Comment: *In the old days, some people used `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` or `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`...* I would use the much cleaner `Map.entry()` introduced in Java 9.

Comment: @shmosel I added a mention of that too, for completeness. Thank you.

Comment: I meant this static factory method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entry-K-V-

Comment: @shmosel Yep, I added that a moment ago.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the problem correctly, you need to obtain only a single object for which your function produces maximum and its corresponding value.

Judging by the usage of `get()`, I assume that you're OK with throwing an exception in case if the optional is empty. If you're using Java 10+ [`orElseThrow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow()) is a preferred option because it explicitly conveys your intention to the reader of the code.

Here's how you can generate an auxiliary `Map` and associating each object with a *value* returned by the function using [`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)), and then pick the *entry* containing the *highest value*.

```
Map.Entry<MyType, Float> maxEntry = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Function.identity(),        // key
        t -> complexFunction(x, t), // value
        (left, right) -> left       // resolving duplicates
    ))
    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .orElseThrow();

MyType maxElement = maxEntry.getKey();
float maxFunctionValue = maxEntry.getValue();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a valid alternative solution